# How to exclude a label in neo4j for relationship

Tags: neo4j, cypher, cql

I am new to Neo4j, I want to show all the relations excluding a label.

I am doing :

```
match ()-[p:PLAYED]->() where not p:Today return p
```

But is giving me the following error

```
Type mismatch: expected Node but was Relationship (line 1, column 37 (offset: 36))
"match ()-[p:PLAYED]->() where not p:Today return p"
```

It's working for excluding node labels but not for the relationships, i am not able to get a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relationships do not have **label**s, only nodes have.
Relationships have a single **type**.
In your query, `p` is already of type `PLAYED` so it cannot be of any other type.

Moreover, `p:Today` is the syntax for **label** predicates, but `p` is bound to a relationship, hence the error.

If you had a less constrained pattern such as `()-[p]->()`, then you could check the type with `TYPE(p)`. Note however that you will end up traversing the whole connected graph with this pattern.